# При загрузки формы выдает ошибку связанную с Ядром СУБД

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, access

Ошибка: Ядру СУБД Microsoft Access не удается найти входную таблицу или запрос "Questions". Убедитесь, что объект существует, а его имя указано правильно.

Используется СУБД Access

```
public partial class TestLesson : Window
{
    private readonly MobileContext _context =
        new MobileContext();
    public TestLesson()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int time;


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        _context.Questions.Load(); // Ядро Субд ошибка
    }
    public void GoToTimer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time++;
            textBlockTimer.Text = ($"{time / 60}:{time % 60}");

            if (time == Convert.ToInt32(_context.Questions.Local.ToObservableCollection().Select(t => t.time).FirstOrDefault()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс связи с бд

```
public class MobileContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Action> ActionsAll { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ButtonGen> ButtonGens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        optionsBuilder.UseJet(Properties.Settings.Default.BDConnectionString);

    }
}
```

Класс объекта

```
[Table(Name = "Question")]
    public class Question
    {
        [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "Вопрос")]
        public string question { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "Ответ")]
        public string answerOne { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "Ответ2")]
        public string answerTwo { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "Ответ3")]
        public string answerThree { get; set; }

         [Column(Name = "Ответ4")]
        public string answerFour { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "ОтветПрав")]
        public string answerTrue { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "TestId")]
        public int idTest { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "Image")]
        public string time { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скрине нет имени таблицы, только поля. Зачем он здесь? Ошибка же не про поля, верно? Убедитнсь, что таблица называется именно `Questions` как указано в контексте, а не например `Question`.

Comment: Таблица называется Question

Comment: А здесь у таблицы другое название `public DbSet<Question> Questions`,

Comment: Да, спасибо больше, разобрался. Это был мой затуп.